# Rails, RSpec unit test failing for username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, unit-testing, rspec

total n00b here. I'm trying to figure out how to write unit tests for my user model. It's currently failing for 4 of my tests and I'm having a hell of a time figuring out why.

The first failure is for this line...

`it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:username) }` fails with rails responding...

```
1) User should require case sensitive unique value for username
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:username) }

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "seeking_coach" violates not-null constraint
       DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, , , , , a, , , , , null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, null, null, null, null, 2016-10-30 19:17:07.366431, 2016-10-30 19:17:07.366431, f, null, null, null).
       : INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
```

Why is this unit test of username failing due to a null field while the prior unit test (`it { should have_valid(:username).when('Groucho', 'Marx')}`) passes?

## spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
  it { should have_valid(:username).when('Groucho', 'Marx')}
  it { should_not have_valid(:username).when(nil, '')}
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:username) }
```

## models/user.rb

```
  validates :username, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates_format_of :username, with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z/
```

Comment: Could you please consider splitting your questions up into multiple posts instead of rolling them all into one big question. It's can be quite daunting for people to read through all this and answer every question you have. Other good reasons to split it can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts?newreg=37fbd29e1ac847c2a7fa80de6a2ad2ee). You will get much more positive response if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Good advice. I'll edit it now accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Why one test is given the null constraint and the other isn't is a bit of a puzzle - the only thing I can imagine is that either a before_action in your model or a before trigger in your database is setting the value of seeking_coach based on username - is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, having read around it appears this may actually be a bug related to the shoulda matcher for some edge case when testing for uniqueness with a NOT NULL database constraint on a different column.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/600

As a workaround I would suggest that you explicitly set up a valid model and allow the shoulda matcher to do its own thing on the attribute to be tested. You can set the subject that all shoulda matchers should use like so:

```
describe User do
  subject { User.new(
    username: 'username',
    seeking_coach: 'coach',
    #
    # set other valid attributes here
    #
  )}

  it { should have_valid(:username).when('Groucho', 'Marx')}
  it { should_not have_valid(:username).when(nil, '')}
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:username) }
end
```

Of course if you are using FactoryGirl, and have a user factory that can build a valid user, then you can simply use:

```
subject { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
```

Now all the shoulda matcher tests will use that object to run the tests with, and you shouldn't get database constraint issues for an attribute you aren't testing.

Comment: Possibly your other issues are related to this, but if not please post a new question and leave this one as is :)

Comment: This fixed the username uniqueness validation! Thank you! I'm looking at the other issues now. Hopefully this will help.